# Whom to send pull request when forked a forked repo?

Tags: github

I have forked osm0sis/boot-unlocker which is a fork of segv11/boot-unlocker because osm0sis's fork was ahead of segv11 
I made few fixes and issued a pull request. The pull request was automatically sent to osm0sis (later I noticed there was an option to choose where to send the PR). Now I have been added as a contributor to osm0sis's fork but not in segv11's fork but I intended to contribute to original project (which is segv11/boot-unlocker). Should I continue sending PRs to osm0sis or send the future PRs to segv11? segv11's repo is behind osm0sis. What is the correct workflow? Issue PR to the most upto date fork or the original repo?

A more important thing is, which repo should I set my uptream as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what your goals are.

Typically you would send PRs to the original project and (hopefully) get those signed off and merged by its maintainers.

The main reason you would send PRs to a fork (`osm0sis/boot-unlocker` in this case) instead of the original project is if the fork will evolve and live as a separate project, never intending to merge with the original one **and** you want to contribute to that fork of the project because you agree with this other person's vision, etc...

`upstream` should be the project you intend to contribute to... Depending on what you decide based on the above.

---

> Here is the **GitHub Standard Fork & Pull Request Workflow**:
>   https://gist.github.com/augustoproiete/256b560d008d39afc0814a19f41a1d49

You may also be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48435518).

Comment: The project is an android app which will be updated only by segv11 on playstore. But he doesn't seem to maintain the repo anymore. osm0sis is actively working on it but he cannot update the app on playstore. Should I still set upstream to osm0sis?

Comment: I have visited both links before posting this question :)

Comment: You have to talk with these developers to see what's the future of either repositories, and then decide where you should be contributing to and spending your time... Ultimately, you can keep your own fork for your own purposes...